# Encryption issue with php

Tags: php, ios, cakephp, cryptography, aes

Doing AES256 encryption on server and decryption on ios. That didn't work for a long time, but I decided to base 64 encode text to encrypt before encrypting.

Accidentally I put braces around base64_encode($source) and that started work. So now this wrong code works(decrypts well on ios):

```
$ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, "base64_encode($source)", MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

and right thing doesn't work at all:

```
$ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_encode($source), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

Using cake php if that makes the difference. What is wrong and what is the difference? Why braces make thing to work and without braces it just fails on decryption? Sorry, if it is very stupid question, but I am new to cryptography.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should character-encode the plain text (e.g. use UTF-8, there is a utf8-encode function in PHP), and then base64 encode the outcome if you want to transfer the result as a string.

Note that the output of mcrypt_encrypt() will be indistinguishable from random bytes. That mean that any bytes can be output, including those that are not valid character encodings (such as a 00h valued byte, or EOF in C). As the IV is random (hopefully) sometimes everything will seem peachy, and sometimes your decryption will fail because of an invalid character.

With encryption, if you are not in full control over the (charachter) encoding/decoding principles (not so much encryption/decryption), then you may get unexpected outcomes *once in a while* - just the thing you need to avoid when programming something.